# how can i download and install github on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I am new to ubuntu and I want to install git hub in Ubuntu. I find download page [here](http://git-scm.com/download/linux) but when I run:

> apt-get install git

on terminal then I got error like:

> E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock -open(13: Permission
>   denied)

How can I download and install git hub on Ubuntu?

I'm  new to github and ubuntu. Anyways, I've messed with Windows and Github, where when I install git, I can an actual application that runs, and I can open git bash. But when I just try to install github on Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install git`, I got an error:

> E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock -open(13: Permission denied)

Comment: `git` is an open-source version control system. [GitHub](https://github.com/) is a web site where you can host public `git` repositories (and restricted ones for premium users). You can license their oftware for your own use so you can have your own private GitHub site, but I'm guessing that's not what you want at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `apt-get` correctly, that error means that something else is installing or upgrading something on your ubuntu box, most likely the automatic updates process.

Just try again in some minute with `sudo apt-get install git`, or use the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: @tripleee But since you wrote in the question that the command you issued included `sudo`, the only other explanation was the one that I gave you.